# Origin of the $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ notation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have the following exercise:

Show that closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\mathbb{\mathbb{R}} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$, justifying the notation $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, for the order topology.

The definition of closure of a set $A$ that I have is it being the intersection of all closed sets containing A.

Now, if $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, why does the closure have to include $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is already closed in the standard topology. Previous to this claim there has to be a definition of a different topology, like the metric topology to $d(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$ where $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$, so that then the sequence $x_n=n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Yeah, that exercise doesn't make sense. I'm guessing they're referring to the completion of $\mathbb R$ under some different distance function as well.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I will correct the question, here I have to consider $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with the order topology, but I still don't see how that changes anything

Comment: I suppose the invocation of "order topology" will lead to using $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$ and $\sup\Bbb R=+\infty$ in some way. Or that every nested sequence of closed intervals has points in their intersection, and then use the sets $\{x\ge n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could regard it as a simple abuse of notation, but it is a *motivated* abuse of notation.

In the topological space $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$ with the order topology, the closure of the subset $\mathbb R$ is equal to the whole space $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$. So the following equation is simply true in that topological space:
$$\overline{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}
$$
So, now, which one would you rather write or even read? $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$ or $\overline{\mathbb R}$? Those who like brevity of notation, even at the expense of abuse of notation, will use that equation as motivation (and "justification") for choosing $\overline{\mathbb R}$.

Let me also add that a topologist might go further down the "justification" path as follows: as in any topological space, it is obvious that the closure of $\mathbb R$ in itself is $\mathbb R$. So why waste good notation like $\overline{\mathbb R}$ on the closure of $\mathbb R$ in itself?

Most abuses of notation are motivated or justified in some such fashion, but that's a much longer story...

Comment: Why does the "closure of the subset R is equal to the whole space R∪{−∞,+∞}", at least according to the definition I gave?

Comment: Let me ask two questions: Do you understand the order relation on $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$? And do you understand the order topology, and a basis for the order topology?

Comment: Yes. It's the set of  all open intervals $(a,b)$, including $[-\infty, a)$ and $(b,+\infty]$. For every $x\in U$, being U an open interval, there must exist an interval  I such that $x\in U$ and $I\subset U$

Comment: correction: $x\in I$    *

Comment: So, in the topological space $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$, *every* basis interval that contains $-\infty$ also contains a point of $\mathbb R$; therefore, $-\infty$ is in the closure of $\mathbb R$. Similarly, *every* basis interval that contains $+\infty$ also contains a point of $\mathbb R$; therefore, $+\infty$ is in the closure of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I thought that by "subset $\mathbb{R}$" in your answer you meant the usual real number line, not the "extended"

Comment: That is correct: in my answer, and my comments, $\mathbb R$ refers to the usual real number line. In that phrase, by calling it the "subset $\mathbb R$", I was referring the the fact that the usual real number line $\mathbb R$ is a subset of the larger set $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139699/discussion-between-jose-pedro-ferreira-and-lee-mosher).